# How to configure kotlin script project with dependency on current module?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

I'd like to have:

- directory with `.kts` files inside
- classic `src/main/kotlin/my/package` module with classes

And have usage like:

```sh
kotlin my-script.main.kts
```

Where script looks like `my-script.main.kts` this from [the example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-script-examples/blob/master/jvm/main-kts/scripts/kotlinx-html.main.kts)

```kotlin
#!/usr/bin/env kotlin

@file:Repository("https://jcenter.bintray.com")
@file:DependsOn("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:0.6.11")

import kotlinx.html.*; import kotlinx.html.stream.*; import kotlinx.html.attributes.*;
import my.package.*;

val addressee = args.firstOrNull() ?: "World"

print(createHTML().html {
    body {
        h1 { +"Hello, $addressee! from ${my.package.Greater.hello()}" }
    }
})
```

Restrictions:

- no jar dependencies, at first publishing jar to maven repo then run script
- clean design, it should be extendable and as not hello world project

How to configure kotlin script project with dependency on current module?
What are the best practices so far?